# Getting divorced in the UK but the spouse is living abroad

Tags: united-kingdom, divorce

How to get a divorce after the spouse left the UK with no intention to come back?
Both consent to the divorce but the spouse living abroad can't afford to travel.

Comment: I don't think there is a need to travel. Documents can be sent to your spouse as part of the process. The important thing is that your partner consents to the divorce.

Answer (score 2):

You can fill in the divorce petition or dissolution application with their current, or last known, address. You’ll have to pay a £593 court fee.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/divorce-missing-husband-wife

There are other factors you may need to take into account, you should consider getting legal advice